# Repeating nested JSON in angularjs with dot notation in HTML?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am really having a hard time repeating nested objects that are loaded from a json file. I have seen examples of people using dot notations in their HTML for retrieving nested data in JSON, but I can't figure out how this would work for me. The JSON is valid, but I am new to Angular. Could somebody give me a push in the right direction? I would like to enter the name of my menu-card and display it in separate lists. This is what I have and it does not work, (the console does not give me any errors if you are wondering):

```
<div ng-controller="menu" ng-repeat="item in menu.voorgerecht">
        <div>{{item.naam}}</div>

</div>
```

js

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("menu", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.menu = null;
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'menu-items.json'
            }).succes(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.menu = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
});
```

json

```
{
        "voorgerecht": [
            {
                "naam": "Sardine"
            },
            {
                "naam": "Funghi Trifolati"
            }
        ],
        "pizza": [
            {
                "naam": "San Marco"
            },
            {
                "naam": "Capriciosa"
            }
        ],
        "desert": [
            {
                "naam": "Sorbet"
            },
            {
                "naam": "Dame Blanche"
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do `ng-repeat` on the same element that has `ng-controller`:

```
<div ng-controller="menu">
  <div ng-repeat="item in menu.voorgerecht">
    <div>{{item.naam}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not work. I feel like I am missing something with the structure of my JSON file. It is really becoming a headache :)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it not display "Sardine" and "Funghi Trifolati"?

Comment: Well, you also have an typo - it should be `.success` with two `s`. Otherwise, something else is going on that you haven't posted, since this works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4EyzU2zf7qhmB8JtOIU?p=preview

Comment: You get the credits for spotting the typo. Thanks a lot mate! I always post all my relevant code by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<div ng-controller="menu">
   <div ng-repeat="item in menu.voorgerecht">
      {{ item.naam }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk195c6z/)

Comment: How is this fundamentally different than my answer posted 15 minutes before?

Comment: I have tested this already in a fiddle with a variable. The problem is that when I am loading data from a JSON file I can't get it to work.

Comment: typo hah. nice catch @NewDev, BTW, by the time I composed my answer you posted your code. I am new to stack over flow :)